# Why does the MASM symbol RAX return true for both IFDEF and IFNDEF?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm64

Recently was working on a project to include 64-bit code when assembled under ML64.exe. However, this code actually included the 32-bit MASM directives, so the build failed.

```
IFNDEF RAX

.686P
.MODEL FLAT,STDCALL
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE
OPTION PROLOGUE:W32Prologue

ELSE

OPTION CASEMAP:NONE
OPTION PROLOGUE:W64Prologue
OPTION EPILOGUE:NONE

ENDIF
```

The fix was to change IFNDEF RAX to IFDEF RAX as follows

```
IFDEF RAX

OPTION CASEMAP:NONE
OPTION PROLOGUE:W64Prologue
OPTION EPILOGUE:NONE

ELSE

.686P
.MODEL FLAT,STDCALL
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE
OPTION PROLOGUE:W32Prologue

ENDIF
```

Wrote a simple example to show why using IFNDEF RAX is misleading

**rax.asm**

```
option casemap:none

extrn printf:proc

.data

     szRAX db 'Symbol RAX exists',0ah,0
     
.code

main proc
    
     ifdef   RAX
     mov     rcx,offset szRAX
     call    printf
     endif     

     ifndef  RAX
     mov     rcx,offset szRAX
     call    printf  
     endif
  
     ret
     
main endp

end
```

Building and running shows this output

```
C:\masm32>ml64.exe rax.asm /link /subsystem:console /defaultlib:kernel32.lib /defaultlib:user32.lib /defaultlib:libcmt.lib
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler (x64) Version 14.29.30146.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: rax.asm
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30146.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/OUT:rax.exe
rax.obj
/subsystem:console
/defaultlib:kernel32.lib
/defaultlib:user32.lib
/defaultlib:libcmt.lib

C:\masm32>rax.exe
Symbol RAX exists
Symbol RAX exists
```

Why does MASM output the same string twice?

Comment: I wouldn't expect RAX to be a preprocessor symbol / macro; it's a register name. Presumably there is something you can check for that does work reliably to detect bitness, similar to how C `#ifdef __x86_64__` works, but I don't know what MASM defines.  Still I guess it's interesting that using a register name breaks MASM so badly that `ifdef` and `ifndef` are both true for the same name.

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595550/detecting-architecture-at-compile-time-from-masm-masm64